# Uploading to S3 from Django

Tags: html, django, url, amazon-s3

I'm trying to add functionality to my Django site to upload files to an AWS S3 bucket. I found [django-s3direct](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct), which seems perfectly suited. After following all the setup instructions, though, I'm getting an error rendering the very basic HTML template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>s3direct</title>
    {{ form.media }}
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error `Reverse for 's3direct' not found. 's3direct' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` on the line with `{{ form.as_p }}`.

In my `urls.py` I have (as specified in the s3direct docs):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import get_upload_params, generate_aws_v4_signature, MyView
app_name = 's3direct'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MyView.as_view(), name='form'),
    url('^get_upload_params/', get_upload_params, name='s3direct'),
    url('^get_aws_v4_signature/', generate_aws_v4_signature, name='s3direct-signing'),
]
```

In `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from s3direct.widgets import S3DirectWidget
class S3DirectUploadForm(forms.Form):
    csv = forms.URLField(widget=S3DirectWidget(dest='csv_destination'))
```

And in `views.py` (along with a couple other long functions from s3direct):

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import S3DirectUploadForm
class MyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'form.html'
    form_class = S3DirectUploadForm
```

I've configured an IAM policy and added keys to my Django settings file, as well as made a CORS policy for my S3 bucket. I'm using Django 2.0. I'm stuck on this reverse error, and can't seem to figure out what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs urls.py should contain

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^s3direct/', include('s3direct.urls')),
 ]
```